# media part in django is not coming

Tags: python, django

I cant upload an image file. media file doesn't come in django when i upload an image.
i add settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
def addArticle(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        article = form.save(commit=False)
        article.author = request.user
        article.save()
        messages.success(request,"Makale Başarıyla Oluşturuldu.")
        return redirect("index")
    return render(request,"addarticle.html",{"form":form})
```

forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ["title","content","article_image"]
```

when i upload an image in to my article i got nothing to view
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete = models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Yazar")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50,verbose_name="Başlık")
    content = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Oluşturulma Tarihi")
    article_image = models.FileField(blank = True, null= True,verbose_name = "Fotoğraf Ekleyin.")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Do you have a view/template where you are trying to view the image? Can you also add the model to your question

Comment: `<img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{article.article_image.url}}" alt="">` im trying to view the image like this.

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag in the template?

Comment: this solved my problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries, you need to include that `enctype` for all forms with file inputs